# Recover AndroidRuntime error generated by my android application on a file

Tags: android, runtime-error, logcat

I would like to recover the Androidruntime errors caused by my application for put this on the String or on a file...

For example : java.lang.NullPointerException, java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException etc... generated by ymy app.

I've try this method :

[..]
// logcat AndroidRuntime:E | grep com.eloges.downgrade

String command  = "logcat AndroidRuntime:E"; 
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {//
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");

        } [..]
```

But, if my application crash, the Service within my app which running this code can't work also...

I've try to recover all messages filtered by my app  (logcat com.package) or ( adb logcat com.package)  but it doesn't work... The logcat put :

```
java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [adb, logcat, com.[..].package Working Directory: null Environment: null
```

So, what are your methods to save a file the logcat of your application ? especially AndroidRuntime errors ?

Comment: Forget the question for now.  **What** functionality are you trying to achieve and **why** do you need it.  There is probably a much better solution.

Comment: I would like to establish a Report Bugs within my application, I found "ACRA" https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup   I think that it's a better track ?